Busted recoil on Westinghouse 5300dfcv generator
I was trying to start my gen the other day and the thing kicked back and tore up the plastic housing in the recoil. I was able to get a few more pulls out of the recoil, but I cant get a full pull of the rope. Feels like it's trying to compress a basketball. I can pull the plug out and things move freely when rotating the crank.
The valve lash on the intake and exhaust valves was a off a couple thousandths so got that adjusted back to spec but not sure it's going to work until I get a new recoil delivered.
I was looking for that small bump on the exhaust valve when rotating the crank for the automatic compression release but I couldn't see anything there.
I could still check the keyway and coil/mag if this doesn't do it but not sure what else it could be.  Does anyone know if ACR is implemented differently on these?

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Fuel selector left on (gasoline), allowing gravity feed to flood the engine? Carburetors with floats control fuel flow. The float needle stuck open from debris may flood the cylinder, Liquid fuel is incompressible and one reason the piston cannot reach top dead center when its trying to compress a liquid. If flooding occurs, the carburetor may need to be removed, disassembled, cleaned and checked for debris. Water in fuel may have minerals, settling and forming deposits, interfering with carb control. Plug removed, pull several times to clear all fuel from the cylinder then try again.

Thanks. Could be. I usually turn the gas off when I park it. Had just been running the gen like a minute before the recoil busted so gas wasn't sitting on too long. I left the plug out for a few days to dry it out but still no luck. I'm able to start it with one of those widow-makers and a 3/8 adapter for my drill. If anyone tries this, make sure to get a clutch (https://www.amazon.com/dp/B01MSZBDFN) and wrap duct tape over all the joints so the thing doesn't come apart and start whipping things all over when you pull it off.
